# Is it possible to display latest comment I made in issues globally in github using web ui?

Tags: github

I've added a few comments on issues that bothers me in a few repositories. I'd like to search for them. Is it possible to find them using github web ui ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the top right bell icon (notifications), then go to the tab `Subscriptions`. You should be able to find your stuff there.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me!